# Error when running tests in VueJS: Unknown custom element: <router-link>

Tags: jasmine, vue.js, karma-runner, vuejs2

When I run my Karma/Jasmine tests I get a Error Log in the console after mounting my header component which include `<router-link>` components. It all run's perfectly fine but just can't seem fix the error that displays. The error is:

```
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. (found in <Header>)'
```

I have done the old: `Vue.use(VueRouter)` and am running `"vue-router": "^2.4.0",`

Any help would be much appreciated

---

SiteHeader.html

```
<header class="site-header">
 <div class="site-header__home-btn">
  <router-link to="home">Home</router-link>
 </div>
 <div class="site-header__info-bar">
  Info bar
 </div>
</header>
```

SiteHeader.vue

```
<template src="./SiteHeader.html"></template>
<style scoped lang="sass" src="./SiteHeader.scss"></style>

<script>
export default {
 name: 'site-header'
}
</script>
```

SiteHeader.spec.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SiteHeader from '../SiteHeader.vue'

describe('SiteHeader', () => {

 /*
  * Template
  *
  */
 describe('Template', () => {
   it('should render a SiteHeader component', () => {
     const vm = new Vue(SiteHeader).$mount()
     expect(vm.$el).toBeTruthy()
   })
 })
})
```

Full Error:

```
ERROR LOG: TypeError{stack: 'render@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:33404:21
_render@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:7488:26
updateComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6037:28
get@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6348:29
Watcher@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6331:15
mountComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6041:28
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:11131:24
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:13180:20
init@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6810:19
createComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:8535:10
createElm@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:8478:24
createChildren@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:8603:18
createElm@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:8511:23
createChildren@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:8603:18
createElm@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:8511:23
patch@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:8934:16
_update@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:5914:28
updateComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6037:17
get@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6348:29
Watcher@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6331:15
mountComponent@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:6041:28
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:11131:24
$mount@http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:13180:20
http://localhost:9876/base/index.js?0474196dfad39c6ebb985b02818a594daecdb5f6:42444:62
attemptSync@http://localhost:9876/absolute/Users/user/projects/project/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?916005cc407925f4764668d61d04888d59258f5d:1950:28
```

Comment: Can you please add the unit test code?

Comment: Does it work when opening it directly? (not in the test context) ?

Comment: Yup, works like a charm normally but just error's in test. Will add some test code up top

Comment: before you do this: `const vm = new Vue(SiteHeader).$mount()`, add `Vue.use('vueRouter)'` also add `import vueRouter from 'vue-router'` Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amresh Venugopal is mostly right, but You also need to provide `vm` instance  with `VueRouter` instance (its also important to provide routes config that matches needs of ). Basically issue here is caused because router is `undefined`. Porper routes config is required, otherwise You will get error that `'home'` route is not defined.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SiteHeader from '../SiteHeader.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

describe('SiteHeader', () => {
  /**
  * Template
  *
  */
  describe('Template', () => {
    it('should render a SiteHeader component', () => {
      Vue.use(vueRouter)
      const routes = { ... };
      const router = new VueRouter({
        routes,
        // some other config
      });
      vm = new Vue({
        template: '<div><site-header></site-header></div>',
        router: router,
        components: {
            site-header: SiteHeader
        }
      }).$mount()

      // some expects...
    })
  })
})
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Vue natively doesn't have the `<router-link>` component. It comes along with the `vue-router` plugin. In your unit-test code, the vue instance doesn't have the `vue-router` plugin added, leading to the error you are facing.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SiteHeader from '../SiteHeader.vue'
import vueRouter from 'vue-router'

describe('SiteHeader', () => {
  /**
  * Template
  *
  */
  describe('Template', () => {
    it('should render a SiteHeader component', () => {
      Vue.use(vueRouter)
      const vm = new Vue(SiteHeader).$mount()
      expect(vm.$el).toBeTruthy()
    })
  })
})
```

Now the `vm` should have access to the `<router-link>` and `<router-view>` components.

Comment: Thanks for this! I haven't had chance to run it yet, but will approve it as soon as I do. Thanks again for the swift response 

Comment: Unfortunately  this didn't working in my case. I'm going to keep investigating so will keep you posted if I find a fix that works for me.

Comment: I just this this one: `ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in render function: 
(found in <RouterLink>)'` with a big stacktrace

Comment: So that means it does identify `<router-link>`. Can you post an image of the error?

Comment: Just added the error. It only error's on templates that have the `router-link` component in. It's super annoying as the stack trace is a whopper

Comment: it looks like your test code is going into a minified file, is that the case? all the errors are in one file with a hash, so it seems to me that it is a minified file.

Comment: I guess so, that would be for the coverage report?

Comment: well, tests must run before minification. if in your karma.config if you are directly porting webpack.config, you can use `delete webpack.config` uglifyjs property. That should help.